# Getting the match value of re.search python

Tags: string, python-3.x, jupyter

I'm pulling some data out of the web utilizing python in the Jupyter notebook. I have pulled down the data, parsed, and created the data frame. I need to extract a number out of a string that I have in the data frame. I utilizing this regex to do it:

```
for note in df["person_notes"]:
    print(re.search(r'\d+', note))
```

and the outcome is the following:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(53, 55), match='89'>
```

How can I get just the match number; in this line would be 89. I tried to convert the whole line to `str()` and the `replace()`, but not all lines have the `span=(number, number)` iqual. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `re.search(r'\d+', note).group()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `start()` and `end()` methods on the returned match objects to get the correct positions within the string:

```
for note in df["person_notes"]:
    match = re.search(r'\d+', note)
    if match:
        print(note[match.start():match.end()])
    else:
        # no match found ...
```